# how to rotate a group of nodes around another node javafx

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I have a group of Nodes and I need to rotate the group around a node that is not in the group. How cam I achieve this?

I tried different options with adding panes and played with PathTransition but none of my tries worked

```
var objects = new Group();
objects.getChildren().addAll(element1, element2, andSoOn);

var Earth = new Sphere(10);
//i need the group to rotate (orbit) around this node
var movement = new PathTransition(new Duration(360_00), new Circle(150), Earth);
movement.play();//Earth is rotating around the center of the project. this part works fine
```

when i set the group (objects) as nodes for PathTransition, it comiled, but threw a RuntimeException

Comment: You can get some ideas from [here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835).  Read about the game loop.

Comment: Thank you! But I forgot to mention one thing. The node (Earth) is in movement (rotating around the Sun)

Comment: Animating a [`Rotate` transformation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/transform/Rotate.html) using `Timeline` should do the trick. If the center of the rotation moves, you may need to bind the pivot coordinates instead of simply setting them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rotation around a stationary sun can be achieved as follows:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Orbit extends Application {

    private static final double WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 400, EARTH_RADIUS = 150;
    private Rotate earthRotate;
    private Circle earth;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setTitle("Rotation transformation example");

        var sun = new Sphere(20);
        sun.setTranslateX(WIDTH/2);   sun.setTranslateY(HEIGHT/2);

        earth = new Circle(10);
        earth.translateXProperty().bind(sun.translateXProperty());
        earth.translateYProperty().bind(sun.translateYProperty().subtract(EARTH_RADIUS));
        earthRotate = new Rotate(0, 0, EARTH_RADIUS);
        earth.getTransforms().add(earthRotate);

        Pane root = new Pane(sun, earth);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        animate();
    }

    private void animate() {

        Timeline earthTimeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(earthRotate.angleProperty(), 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(earthRotate.angleProperty(), 360))
         );
        earthTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        earthTimeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I missed the substract part